# can't install ruby iconv gem: Failed to build gem native extension with ruby 2.0, but works with ruby 1.9.3 with the same command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-2.0, iconv

using the same line succeeded on ruby 193 but failed on ruby 200.

```
gem install iconv --platform=ruby -- --with-iconv-lib="C:/iconv/lib" --with-iconv-include="C:/iconv/include"
```

gets

```
ERROR: Error installing iconv:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

Cmd input and output (same line on 193 works, on 200 not):

```
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f9cfbb65e5aef043242973f92fcb4f25
```

mkmf.log:

```
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d270011e167dbcc68ec5670aefed269f
```

C:/iconv file list:

```
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b2528168cfdade18815a12c002a64f16
```

Downloaded iconv from: (Complete package, except sources, version 1.9.2)

```
http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libiconv.htm
```

Notes:

- Searched the internet before asking, really good.
- looked at the mkmf.log, following the compilation lines, but could not understand the problem.
- I know iconv is deprecated and String encode can be used instead, but the code I'm running is not mine and I'm not allowed to edit it.

Comment: seems it requires new version of **iconv.h** to compile

Comment: Thanks @МалъСкрылевъ, I've downloaded the latest version from:
http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libiconv.htm
Do you know the location of newer version?

Comment: I believe  here is: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/downlinks/libiconv-src-zip.php, no, even here: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/downlinks/libiconv-lib-zip.php

Comment: Thanks @МалъСкрылевъ, I've checked and this is the same version as I've downloaded.both are "LibIconv 1.9.2" in the manifest and both files: iconv.h,libiconv.lib are binary the same.
Do you have another idea?